# wrapping/overriding a ContentProvider

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider

Is it possible to wrap an existing ContentProvider?  Basically, I'm tired of every app wanting all of my info so I'd like to write something that catches calls for my location, identity, etc. and decides whether to pass it through or return fake data based on the caller.  Is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I'm tired of every app wanting all of my info so I'd like to write something that catches calls for my location, identity, etc. and decides whether to pass it through or return fake data based on the caller

You could have this as part of your own custom firmware, where you refactor all existing `ContentProviders` into new authorities, so yours can take over.

Otherwise, no -- the first provider in for a particular authority "wins", and therefore the firmware always wins. You cannot override a built-in provider.

Comment: hmm, I was afraid of that.  Similar question... I'd like to make an app that sends my calls to voicemail (or mutes them) after a certain time at night, except for those people on a VIP list.  Is this the same type of issue?

Comment: @user1368550: You can use `AudioManager` to adjust the stream associated with the ringtone, for a mute feature.

Comment: so the ringtones of the VIP contacts would need to be separate from all the other people?  I'd also want to mute (or vibrate) all other notifications during that time period.